# Marker set to draggable cannot be dragged

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This one has me stumped, and I'm hoping a second set of eyes will be able to point out the problem. I realize that my abstraction library adds a lot of additional complexity, but I was thinking that someone else may have seen something similar in their implementation. I've also tried to boil this down to as simple and targeted a case as possible.

The problem is that markers created and added to the map via the Google Maps API and set as draggable cannot be dragged. This used to work just fine, but a change I made somewhere in the library broke this functionality. To reproduce, go to http://www.nps.gov/npmap/support/library/examples/map-defaults.html?api=google and then paste the following code in the browser web development console:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: NPMap.Map.Google.map.getCenter(),
  draggable: true,
  map: NPMap.Map.Google.map
});
```

The marker should be draggable, but it is not.

A few notes:

- Markers are still clickable, and it seems like all marker events (mouseover, etc.) are working properly
- Lines and polygons added to the map as editable work fine
- I have played around with the `z-index` of the map div and some of the other elements, but this doesn't seem to be causing the problem
- I am loading the current release version of the Google Maps API, v3.11. I have tested with the frozen version, 3.10, and the experimental version, v3.12, but the problem persists no matter which version is loaded.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**: Strange. Markers added with `draggable: true` don't appear to be clickable. But if a marker is added without specifying `draggable: true`, it does seem to be clickable. It seems like this is probably related.

**UPDATE 2**: A follow up to my first update: Events **are not working** on markers that are created with `draggable: true` and added to the map. You can run the following code after creating the marker to test this out:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Draggable markers work for me in both the current and experimental versions.  Your link isn't working for me so I can't see the rest of your code.

Comment: Yeah, we are apparently having CDN issues at the moment (great timing, right?). I'll try to get an example up someplace else.

Comment: It's back up. At least for the moment.

Comment: In which browser this issue occurs? Tried with firefox, the marker is draggable and also responds to click-event

Comment: I'm seeing the issue in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I was doing something like this to hack around some of the default Google Map controls:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('gmnoprint');

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

This hasn't affected draggable markers in the past, but Google must have made a change in the Maps API and started adding the `gmnoprint` class to draggable markers. Oh well, that's what I get for going outside of the documented API.